# Real Analysis, Folland 3.4.26

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is the question: "If $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are positive, mutually singular Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda + \mu $ is regular, then so are $\lambda$ and $\mu$".

I need a solution for this problem. I can prove the first condition of regularity. Also, I can prove the second condition of regularity in borel sets such that $(\lambda+\mu)(E)< \infty$. How I can solve when $(\lambda+\mu)(E)=\infty$?

Comment: Perhaps include the definition of "regular".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The finiteness of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ on compact sets is immediate from positivity and the corresponding property for $\lambda+\mu$. Let $E$ be a Borel set. By symmetry, it suffices to show that

$$
\lambda(E)=\inf \{\lambda(U): E \subset U, U \text { open }\}
$$
Let $G_{k}=[-k, k]^{n}$ so that $\mathbb{R}^{n}=\bigcup_{k} G_{k}$ and $(\lambda+\mu)\left(G_{k}\right)<\infty .$ Let
$\epsilon>0 .$ By the outer regularity of $\lambda+\mu$ we can find, for each $k$, an open $U_{k} \supset\left(E \cap G_{k}\right)$ with $(\lambda+\mu)\left(U_{k} \backslash\left(E \cap G_{k}\right)\right)<\epsilon 2^{-k}$
Letting $U=\bigcup_{k} U_{k}$, we then have $(\lambda+\mu)(U \backslash E) \leq \epsilon$ and so $\lambda(U \backslash E)<$
$\epsilon$, which gives what is needed, since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary.